# "Don't start blowing up my line"

Tags: phrases

In Le Sserafim's *Perfect Night* there's a line: "Don't start blowing up my line".

> Tonight
> I don't care what's wrong or right
> Don't start blowing up my line
> I'd care at 11:59
> But nothing counts after midnight

What do they mean?

Read the [full lyrics](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/lesserafim/perfectnight.html).

Answer (score 2):

Aight, so . . .

***To blow up a line*** means to petition someone’s phone line with calls or messages.

> **blow up**
>
> To call/text someone repeatedly, or have multiple people call or text
> the same person.
>  <sub>*Kyle was blowing up my phone this morning
> because he wanted some bud.*</sub>
>
> to inundate a device with messages
>  <sub>*I was asleep for only two
> hours and my pager blew up!*</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [Urban Dictionary—blow
> up](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=blow%20up)</sub>

> **What is a Phone Line?**
>
> . . . a phone line is the “address” that people dial to contact each
> other.
>
> <sub>Source: [VoipReview.org—What’s the Difference Between
> a Phone Number, a Line, and an Extension?](https://www.voipreview.org/blog/difference-between-phone-number-exension-line)</sub>

So: *Stop calling/texting me; I’m out having fun.*

Answer (score -1):

It is likely to be a reference to a line of cocaine. The song refers to partying and feeling like magic, so a reference to drug use makes sense.